# Can someone give me a reference to a door in Morrowind?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

This has bothered me for years and it's time I got an answer.

Back when I used to play Morrowind I stumbled on a large stone door somewhere in the wild (mountainous/hilly region if I remember correctly). When I tried to enter it, it gave me a riddle or message and I was unable to get in.

What door was this? How did other players get in? What was beyond the door? Can someone link me a reference to it?

Comment: It would help if you knew the approximate location or at least coloration of the landscape to narrow it down.  Morrowind has lots of those dungeons.  Was it Ashland?  Grassland?

Comment: Yeah I wanted to be more specific, but it was so long ago it's hard to remember. If I ventured a guess it was south east in gray/reddish mountains.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Was it [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Cavern_of_the_Incarnate)?

[image: screenshot]

> the eye of the needle lies in the teeth of the wind
> the mouth of the cave lies in the skin of the pearl
> the dream is the door and the star is the key

It is [part of the main quest in Ashlands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:The_Path_of_the_Incarnate#Third_Trial_Riddle):

> *The eye of the needle* refers to a tall rock column in the Valley of the Wind. *The skin of the pearl* refers to a pale rock on the very top of the column. *The teeth of the wind* refers to Airan's Teeth, two rock spires marking the entrance to the Valley of the Wind. The spires are named after a seer, Airan, who was blessed by Azura. The valley is on the northeast slope of Red Mountain in the center of the island. The mouth to the valley is just east and south of the Daedric Shrine of Zergonipal, which should now be marked on your world map. *The last clue* refers to the star which is actually Azura's Star that is only visible at dawn and dusk (6 to 8 am and pm).
>
> **What it boils down to is that a door at the base of the needle will be open only during the dawn and dusk hours.** To reach it, start at Falasmaryon and head towards the Daedric Shrine of Zergonipal and just east of it you should find two parallel valleys leading towards the south. Take the one to the east, marked by two tall rock spires (Airan's Teeth). Walk all the way to the end of the valley, and wait for the correct time for the door to open.
>
> A quicker and easier way to get there would be to start from Tel Vos and just hike over the mountains to the west. If you go directly west, you should wind up midway through the Valley of the Wind. Simply follow it south the rest of the way.